# restore savedInstanceState not match to stored

Tags: match, store

Why do the "savedInstanceState" I use
  The following problem will happen?
When the program was first runing receive right message.

But when I select video of  video gallery . 
  In 'savedInstanceState'
The "test" to save it
But when recovery was
Equal conditions 'test'
You can not run?
And orders in

```
'Else if (savedInstanceState.getString (" key ")! ="test")'
```

Was run , while the amount of 'savedInstanceState.getString (" key ")'
is The 'test' ?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {

            if (savedInstanceState.getString("key")=="test"){

                TextView txtarr_1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.test_array_1);
                txtarr_1.setText("if(savedInstanceState.getString(key)==test){" + savedInstanceState.getString("key")+"}");

            }
            else if (savedInstanceState.getString("key")!="test") {
                TextView txtarr_3=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.test_array_3);
                txtarr_3.setText( savedInstanceState.getString("key"));

            }       

        }else{
        TextView txtarr_5=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.test_array_5);
        txtarr_5.setText("elseif (savedInstanceState != null)");
        }}

     @Override
     public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         savedInstanceState.putString("key", "test");

         super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

i change code to  :: instead store a string -->store a integer

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   if (savedInstanceState != null) {

   int val=savedInstanceState.getInt("key");

           if (val==123){

    TextView txtarr_1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.test_array_1);

txtarr_1.setText("if == 123{" + savedInstanceState.getInt("key")+"}");


    }
    else if (val!=123) {
    TextView txtarr_3=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.test_array_3);
txtarr_3.setText( savedInstanceState.getString("key"));
    }     

   }else{
TextView txtarr_5=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.test_array_5);
txtarr_5.setText("elseif (savedInstanceState != null)");
   }}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
savedInstanceState.putInt("key", putInt);

    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

In this case the problem can be solved
that's mean :
Was detected  I store 123 and orders Equal to 123  Was conducted
but if i store  123 to form of string 
 run orders not equal 123 execute

in call a new activity To a stored form
and in restore The stored value is different
But when I show exactly the same text?????? 
why?????

Answer (score 0):

> **I found my mistake**

**for string in IF must use equal , not ==**

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    String str =savedInstanceState.getString("key");
    if ( str.equals("test")){

        TextView txtarr_1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.test_array_1);
        txtarr_1.setText("if == test{" + str+"}");

    }
    else if (!str.equals("test")){
        TextView txtarr_3=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.test_array_3);
        txtarr_3.setText("if != test{" + str+"}");

    }       

}else{
TextView txtarr_5=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.test_array_5);
txtarr_5.setText("elseif (savedInstanceState != null)");
}
```